# Sonar server can not be reached

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I got an issue on my sonarQube plugin in jenkins. When i try to compile my project and start sonarQube then, i got an issue :

```
[INFO] Sonar server can not be reached. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url': http://null:9000
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Sonar server can not be reached. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url': http://null:9000
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Sonar server can not be reached. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url': http://null:9000
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.ServerMetadata.connect(ServerMetadata.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
```

But, when i'm looking about my configration, i don't see mistakes...

Can someone help me? :/

LEDUNOIS S

P.S: I tried to post my config images, but i can't...

Comment: sonar.host.url': http://null:9000.  .. NULL ?

Comment: Yes... I don't know where is that null... Here is my settings file : http://hpics.li/66f729b and here my jenkins config http://hpics.li/90a40f4

Comment: My fire wall is blocking to download images. Can you copy paste that configuration as comment

Comment: <profile>
<id>sonar</id>
<activation>
</activation>
<properties>                <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
<sonar.jdbc.driver>org.postgresql.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
<sonar.jdbc.username>postgres</sonar.jdbc.username>
<sonar.jdbc.password>postgres</sonar.jdbc.password>
<sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
</properties>
</profile>

Comment: Can you try with protocol like http:/localhost:9000. I am not sure. But I think it will work. So give http:/localhost:9000 instead of localhost:9000

Comment: It's currently with protocol. It's juste our browser which is transforming the url

Comment: Is SonarQube server can't run without sonarQube runner? I just want to compile with jenkins and see my sonarQube reports

Comment: I tried to run sonarQube runner with the sonar example and i get a : ERROR: Sonar server 'http://localhost:9000/sonar' can not be reached
But i'm currently connected on it...

Comment: Its only a recommended way to analyse. Other options are with maven and ant. http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven This is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes. But when i'm looking the doc to use Sonar with Maven, I don't see any issues on my configuration...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you forgot to set the `Server URL` from:
`Manage Jenkins`-->`Configure System`-->`Sonar installations`-->`Add Sonar`-->`Advanced`-->`Server URL`, but hope this answer helps.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your host name is missing.

http://null:9000

Instead of null you have to give valid hostname

http://mojo.codehaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin/sonar-mojo.html#sonarHostURL

```
 <profile>
  <id>sonar</id>
  <activation>
  <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
 </activation>
  <properties>
  <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
  <sonar.jdbc.driver>org.postgresql.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
  <sonar.jdbc.username>user</sonar.jdbc.username>
  <sonar.jdbc.password>password</sonar.jdbc.password>
  <!-- SERVER ON A REMOTE HOST -->
  <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: I aggree with you but every hostnames i mention are http://localhost:9000 .. You can see my settings file here : http://hpics.li/66f729b

Comment: My fire wall is blocking to download images. Can you copy paste that configuration as comment

Answer (score 0):

In conf folder inside sobarqube installation directory, open sonar.properties and comment out the property sonar.web.host if you have defined an explicit value for the same. This resolved issue for me.